# Help with Reduction of order with independent variable missing - differential equations!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving problems found in the miscellaneous section of Chapter 2 that involve second order linear equations that can be transformed into first-order. Second-order isn't introduced until Chapter 3.

Here's what's given:

**Equations with the Independent Variable Missing**. *Consider second order differential equations of the form y''=f(y,y'),in which the independent variable t does not appear explicitly. If we let v=y', then we obtain dv/dt=f(y,v). Since the right side of this equation depends on y and v,rather than on t and v,this equation contains too many variables. However, if we think of y as the independent variable, then by the chain rule, dv/dt =(dv/dy)(dy/dt)=v(dv/dy). Hence the original differential equation can be written as v(dv/dy)=f(y,v). Provided that this ﬁrst order equation can be solved, we obtain v as a function of y. A relation between y and t results from solving dy/dt=v(y), which is a separable equation. Again, there are two arbitrary constants in the ﬁnal result ($c_1$ and $c_2$).*

1) $yy''+(y')^2 = 0$

2) $2y^2y''+2y(y')^2 =1$

Thanks. I've asked a similar question on solving these problems where dependent variable is unknown, and I was able to solve them all without too much difficulty. These problems however I just don't know where to begin. If someone could show me how to get to the integration part at least, I should be able to handle from there.

**Update**: Here's a screenshot for solution of problem 1. I think I've made a mistake in calculation somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first OE, set $$y=e^{\int u(x)dx}$$ So $$y'=ue^{\int udx}$$ and $$y''=(u'+u^2)e^{\int udx}$$ Now we have $yy''+(y')^2=(u'+u^2)e^{2\int udx}+u^2e^{2\int udx}$ which is zero. Since $e^{2\int udx}\neq 0$ then you should solve $u'+2u^2=0$.

Comment: Nicely done! :+)

Comment: Don't let it get you down. Down votes bother me too. Not because I lose 2 points, but when there is no apparent reason for the downvote, and/or no comment is left explaining it. There is also recently a "serial down-voter" on the loose... so it's probably not anything about you or your work.

Comment: Sorry i am not sure how to solve $u'+2u^2=0$. Do I have to integrate both components?

Comment: Thanks, I found u=1/2x-c. Where do I plug this u into? Is it the 3rd equation in your answer?

Comment: Thank you. I did. I've also included a screenshot of my solution in the question. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @BluePonyInc.: In the line you have $$y= e^{\int\frac{1}{2*x-c_1}}$$ you have $y=\sqrt{2x-c_1}$ instead. It is done.

Comment: @BluePonyInc.: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$